# counterdict unique values Python

Tags: python

Hello I have a counterdict that contains data like this :

```
{1301: Counter({'total': 18, 
               'inDevelopment': 13, 
                'isDuplicate': 2, 
                'inAnalysis': 2,
                'inQuest': 1}),
 1302: Counter({'total': 15, 
                'inDevelopment': 9, 
                 'inQuest': 1, 
                 'inValidation': 1, 
                  'inAnalysis': 1,
                  'ongoing' : 3})}
```

How can I retrieve its values in a list without repetition.
I mean I would like to extract all the existing values, but instead of getting them all, I would like to have them **NOT** duplicated, so instead of this :

```
 [' inDevelopment','isDuplicate','inAnalysis', 'inQuest','total', 'inDevelopment','inQuest', 'inValidation','inAnalysis', 'ongoing']
```

The output would be like this :

```
['total','inDevelopment','isDuplicate','inAnalysis','inQuest','inValidation','ongoing']
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Can you edit and explain what your desired output should look like? It's not quite clear.

Comment: thank you I hope my edit is clearer

Comment: Is that extra space in `' inDevelopment': 13,` meant to be there?  Or are we supposed to get rid of it?

Comment: sorry it was not meant to be there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can union `Counter` objects using `|` operator:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> a = Counter('123')
>>> b = Counter('44144')
>>> a
Counter({'2': 1, '3': 1, '1': 1})
>>> b
Counter({'4': 4, '1': 1})
>>> a | b
Counter({'4': 4, '2': 1, '3': 1, '1': 1})
>>> list(a | b)
['2', '3', '1', '4']
```

*In Python 2.x*

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> d = {1301: Counter({'total': 18,
    ...
...                   "ongoing" : 3})}
>>> list(reduce(lambda a,b:a|b, d.values()))
['inAnalysis', 'inQuest', 'inDevelopment', ' inDevelopment', 'inValidation', 'ongoing', 'isDuplicate', 'total']
```

*In Python 3.x*

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> d = ...
>>> list(reduce(lambda a,b:a|b, d.values()))
['inValidation', 'total', ' inDevelopment', 'inDevelopment', 'isDuplicate', 'ongoing', 'inQuest', 'inAnalysis']
```

### UPDATE

You can also use [`set.union`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#set.union):

```
>>> list(set().union(*d.values()))
['inValidation', 'inDevelopment', 'isDuplicate', 'total', 'ongoing', 'inAnalysis', 'inQuest', ' inDevelopment']
```

This work in both Python 2.x/3.x in one code.

Comment: thank you but in your output "inDevelopment" appears twice, I want the values to be unique...

Comment: I'd avoid `reduce` and go for: `list(set().union(*d.values()))`

Comment: @user1734229, One has a space, while another does not have a space.

Comment: oh it was because of the extra space in " inDevelopment", thanks a lot!

Comment: @JonClements: make than an answer.  I'd tried `set.union(*(map(set,c.values())))`, but I didn't like the duplication of `set`.  `set().union` is perfect.

Comment: @DSM Makes more sense to be part of this answer... (and couldn't be bothered to post an answer :))

Comment: @JonClements, Your suggested code is superior because it works in both Python 2/3 without modification. I updated the answer. Thank you for advice.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `np.unique` with `import numpy as np` and

```
>>> d = {1301: Counter({'total': 18,
                'inDevelopment': 13,
                 'isDuplicate': 2,                 'inAnalysis': 2,
                'inQuest': 1}),
  1302: Counter({'total': 15,                 'inDevelopment': 9,
                  'inQuest': 1,
                  'inValidation': 1,
                   'inAnalysis': 1,
                   "ongoing" : 3})}
```

gives

```
>>> np.unique(list(d[1301]|d[1302]))

array(['inAnalysis', 'inDevelopment', 'inQuest', 'inValidation',
       'isDuplicate', 'ongoing', 'total'], 
      dtype='|S13')
```